# How to do looping and accessing an element from a matrix?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

```
myStr = ['what ' 'am I' 'doing with my life?'];    
wordLength = [4 2 1 5 4 2 4];    
startPos = [1 6 9 11 17 22 25]

for i = ____________________

disp(_________________)

end
```

The question is that I have to fill these blanks such that in each iteration of the loop only one word from the string is printed. I tried doing `i = 1:7`, as well as, `disp(myStr)` but it only printed out the string 7 times.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: You probably should start with a basic MATLAB tutorial first, for exemple https://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/register.html

Comment: [Loops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html) and ["Array" (Matrix)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing with `for` loops is that you need to make use of a **loop index**.  A loop index is a variable that gets updated every time your loop is just about to begin.  How `for` loops work is that you have a body of code that is contained within the `for` loop that gets executed a pre-determined amount of times.  The usual format for a `for` loop is the following:

```
for idx = array
    ... %// BODY
    ...
 end
```

The code within the body of the `for` loop gets executed for as many times as the length of the array in `array`.  Also, `idx` is the **loop index** that I was talking about.  Specifically, the first time the `for` loop executes, `idx` will equal the first element of `array`.  The second time the `for` loop executes, `idx` will equal the second element of `array` and so on.  As such, you can do something very simple like:

```
for idx = 1 : 7
    disp(idx)
end
```

The `for` loop will execute such that the first time it executes the code in `body`, `idx = 1`, the second time the body code executes, `idx = 2`, up until the last element which is `idx = 7`.  Therefore, the above code is equivalent to:

```
disp(1)
disp(2)
disp(3)
disp(4)
disp(5)
disp(6)
disp(7)
```

Instead of writing 7 statements, your `for` loop mimics the same behaviour.  It obviously looks more cleaner.

---

The last thing you need to know is how to index into an array.  I won't go into it in detail as the comments give you some great tutorials on how to do that, but think of an array as a bunch of slots placed together.  Each slot will hold something.  In this case, `myStr` will contain a single string where each slot is a single character.  The array `wordLength` tells you how **long** each word is and `startPos` tells you the position of where each word starts at.

To access a single element in an array, you would do:

```
myStr(k)
```

`k` would be the position of where you want to access in the array.  `k` starts from 1 up until the end of the array.  Another good way of accessing an array is using **indexing**.  Basically, you can grab a whole bunch of values at one time, instead of accessing them in a single fashion like above.  Specifically, you can do this:

```
myStr(first:last)
```

`first` is the starting location of where you want to access and `last` is the last value you want to access.  The output will give you a sequence of values stored in an array that capture those values from `first` to `last` in the array that you want.

---

As such, you have to use the `for` loop as well as the starting position of each string, as well as how long each string is in order to display the complete word.  In other words, you would need to do:

```
for i = 1 : 7
    disp(myStr(startPos(i):startPos(i)+wordLength(i)));
end
```

Also, a minor note.  For this code to work, there should be a **space** after the `I` in your `am I` array.  As such:

```
myStr = ['what ' 'am I ' 'doing with my life?'];
```

In any case, what the above code is saying is that for each value of `i` (`1,2,3,4,5,6,7`), we are going to access the array so that at the starting position for the  i<sup>th</sup> word, we capture as many characters as dictated by the word length of this word.  Let's say the beginning of our first word was in location 3 of our array, and the word is 5 characters long (including the space).  You would essentially grab characters from location 3 up to location 8. and so you would essentially do:

```
mystr(3:8)
```

The `for` loop is essentially doing this, but repeating it for every word in the array.  As such, this is what I get when I run the above code, noting the slight fix in adding a space in the `am I` string.

```
what 
am 
I 
doing 
with 
my 
life?
```